# Return then wait for another function to finish in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My general idea is, that I have a or more test functions which can call another function.
So:

1. test_function does some things, then calls another function
2. Called other function will do something, then return a result and
3. Wait for the test_function to finish, then do everything that is to be done after the "return"

Of course, that does not work with a literal return, so my question is, if there is a possibility I do not see.

A practical example:

Test function in pytest - test_config is a fixture:

```
def test_load_into_database(test_config):
    logger.info('Testing load_into_database')
    data = {
        'filename': 'file_0'
    }
    accessor = list(database_accessor(test_config))[0]
    access_data = accessor['session'].query(accessor['table']).all()
    assert access_data[0].filename != data['filename']
    accessor['session'].add(accessor['table'](
        filename='file_0'
    ))
    accessor['session'].commit()
    access_data = accessor['session'].query(accessor['table']).all()
    assert access_data[0].filename == data['filename']
```

This test function calls another one:

```
def database_accessor(cfg):
    setup = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
        cfg['database_user'],
        cfg['database_passwd'],
        cfg['database_host'],
        cfg['database_db']
    )
    Base = automap_base()
    engine = create_engine(setup, echo=False)
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
    table = Base.classes.get(cfg['database_table'])
    session = Session(engine)
    ->return and wait<- {
        'session': session,
        'table': table
    }
    session.close()
    with engine.connect() as con:
        con.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute("TRUNCATE TABLE {}".format(cfg['database_table']))
```

What I want is, that the database_accessor returns the dictionary, then waits for the underlying function (in this case the test_function) to finish, then resumes.

That way, it is possible to use a variable number of test functions with the same database_accessor without executing all the different test functions in the database_accessor.

**Callbacks**

I know that there is a way, with a callback function, but that doubles my functions, which I do not want. E.g.

```
def test_load_into_database():
    database_accessor(load_into_database_1, var1, var2)

def database_accessor(function, args*):
    # do stuff
    function(args, stuff)
    # do other stuff

def load_into_database_1(args, stuff):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to make `database_accessor` a context manager:

```
with database_accessor(test_config) as accessor:
    access_data = accessor['session'].query(accessor['table']).all()
    assert access_data[0].filename != data['filename']
    accessor['session'].add(accessor['table'](
        filename='file_0'
    ))
    accessor['session'].commit()
    access_data = accessor['session'].query(accessor['table']).all()
    assert access_data[0].filename == data['filename']
```

The implementation would looks something like this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def database_accessor(cfg):
    setup = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
        cfg['database_user'],
        cfg['database_passwd'],
        cfg['database_host'],
        cfg['database_db']
    )
    Base = automap_base()
    engine = create_engine(setup, echo=False)
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
    table = Base.classes.get(cfg['database_table'])
    session = Session(engine)
    try:
        yield {
        'session': session,
        'table': table
        }
    finally:
        session.close()
        with engine.connect() as con:
            con.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute("TRUNCATE TABLE {}".format(cfg['database_table']))
```

In this case, I would modify it slightly to yield a tuple instead of a dict:

```
yield session, table
```

and then, when using it you could do:

```
with database_accessor(test_config) as (session, table):
```

Comment: This is super cool, thank you very much!! I did not know this was possible.